# How to handle OLEDB Destination Error if the table is not exist the database SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, integration

Help in ssis package i have an oledb destination this oledb destination you wiill set a connection to an existing table. The problem is I have a sql task that will check if the table is not exists in the database the task will create a table and will continue to the data flow task.

[image: Control Flow]

[image: Execute SQL Task]

This is the problem I cannot run the package because if the table is not exist in the database the package will return an error.

[image: Data Flow]

Is there anyway that I can run the package and set an oledb destination without the table in the database?

Comment: Have you tried setting the DelayedValidation property of the DataFlow Task?

Comment: Nope. what's the use of that?

Answer (score 1):

Your package is failing because the first thing it does when running is validate everything. However if you set the delayed validation property on your Data Flow task to true, that task will only be checked just before it runs (when the table exists) not on package start up.